# Unpacking array into separate variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a simple problem, and I've done it before. I just can't remember how, or what exactly it was called.

In python I can do this:

```
arr = ['one', 'two']
one, two = arr
```

how do I do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

ES6 allows for destructuring assignment:

```
let [x, y] = ['foo', 'bar'];
console.log(x); // 'foo'
console.log(y); // 'bar'
```

Or, to stick to your initial example:

```
var arr = ['one', 'two'];
var [one, two] = arr;
```

You could also create a default value:

```
const [one = 'one', two = 'two', three = 'three'] = [1, 2];
console.log(one); // 1
console.log(two); // 2
console.log(three); // 'three'
```

Comment: destructuring assignment has full support as of today http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring

Comment: not true, now can be done with the spread syntax:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 33):

The question is rather old but I like to post this alternative (2016) solution: One can also use the *spread* operator "...".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

```
let xAndY = [42, 1337];
let f = function(x, y) { return x + y; };
f(...xAndY);
```

Answer (score 30):

That's [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/new_in_javascript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment_(Merge_into_own_page.2fsection)).  You can do it in some browsers with the following syntax:

```
[one, two] = arr;
```

It's supported in some of the latest browsers and transpilers like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler).  This was a feature introduced with ECMAScript 4 which later became ECMAScript Harmony, which eventually became ES 2015.

Comment: Looks like it's part of ES6 (2015), not ES4? http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment

Comment: @jab: thanks! sometimes these old answers get forgotten about and become outdated, though it looks like Mathias already added that info to his answer :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use array's apply function if you want an array items to be passed as a function arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure a JavaScript `Array` has an `.apply()` function. I think you meant `some_function.apply(this, my_array)`. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077651/python-like-unpacking-in-javascript/7077758#7077758)

Answer (score 6):

Implementation of serious's idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/RichAyotte/6D2wP/

```
(function(a, b, c, d) {
    console.log(a, b, c, d);   
}.apply(this, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

Comment: This one made my day. Unpacking lists via apply, well done sir!

Answer (score 3):

```
var one = arr[0];
var two = arr[1];
```

Comment: You should really use `var` to prevent the variables from polluting the global scope.

Comment: I'm just assuming its all declared variables :)

Comment: It’s probably a better idea to declare all `var` s for each scope in one go rather than having two separate `var` declarations.

Answer (score 3):

The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Here is an example. You can try like this.

```
 let a, b, rest;
[a, b] = [10, 20];

console.log(a);
// expected output: 10

console.log(b);
// expected output: 20

[a, b, ...rest] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

console.log(rest);
// expected output: Array [30,40,50]
```

Answer (score 2):

CoffeeScript has it: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#pattern_matching

And, quoted from the top of the page:

"CoffeeScript is a little language that compiles into JavaScript. Think of it as JavaScript's less ostentatious kid brother — the same genes, roughly the same height, but a different sense of style. Apart from a handful of bonus goodies, statements in CoffeeScript correspond one-to-one with their equivalent in JavaScript, it's just another way of saying it."

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I appreciate that CoffeeScript has some neat things, but the question is about Javascript.

Comment: Dead link :((((

Answer (score 0):

My example works for your example but also if you dont know the array or the array length.

```
arr = ['one', 'two'];
var length = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   var val = arr[i];
   eval('var '+arr[i]+'= arr[i];');
}
```

Know you have 2 variables. The first is 'one' who is "one"and the second is 'two' who is "two".
Your problem is solved!
But for the code snippet, i created extra elements to display the var's and i logged it.

```js
arr = ['one', 'two'];
var length = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   var val = arr[i];
   eval('var '+arr[i]+'= arr[i];');
}
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = one + " " + two;
document.body.appendChild(p);
console.log(one, two);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ['one', 'two'];
var length = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   var val = arr[i];
   eval('var '+arr[i]+'= arr[i];');
}
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = one + " " + two;
document.body.appendChild(p);
console.log(one, two);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.