# Pulling random numbers from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, integer

Quick question.
Let's say you have a string of three numbers separated by spaces, like so:
"123 5235 90" and the length of each number varies.  How could one go about pulling each number to a variable so that 
number1 = 123
number2 = 5235 and number3 = 90.
Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript: split string straight to variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522406/javascript-split-string-straight-to-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` alongside destructuring:

```js
const s = "123 5235 90"
const [number1, number2, number3] = s.split(' ')

console.log(number1)
console.log(number2)
console.log(number3)
```

Should you want the output to be actual numbers instead of strings, you can map over the split like so to convert all elements to numbers:

```
s.split(' ').map(Number)
```