# Destructuring String.split() works in the console, but not in a file

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, destructuring

I had a problem while destructuring the result of an String.split() operation.

**Situation**

This code is present in my index.html page in a `<script>` tag, but I tested it with a separate file, and it has the same behaviour

```js
var timestamp = "2023/06/07T15:50:15.655000";
[timestamp_date, timestamp_time] = timestamp.split("T");
console.log(timestamp_date, timestamp_time);
```

(I also noticed that the code snippet of stackoverflow doesn't throw an error, but isn't printing the result either)

I used Firefox 68.2 and Edge 112.0, and both throws a ReferenceError, saying timestamp_date isn't defined, which I understand, because timestamp_date and timestamp_time are not defined with a var, const or let.

However, when i try to do it in the console, it works just fine.

Also, when I try with a simpler code, it works perfectly without having to define the variables
(It works in the console, but also in a `<script>` tag)

```js
[a,b] = ["1","2"]
console.log(a,b);
```

**So my question is :**
Is it a problem with destructuring and String.split(), or am i missing something ?

**EDIT**

I know that adding const, let or var before the destructuring works, i just want to know why the second case works without

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386234/object-destructuring-without-var-let-or-const

Comment: Arrays don't have a `.split()` method. Perhaps you mean `string.split()`?

Comment: Can you clarify when exactly you are seeing the `ReferenceError`? Are you saying that if you have a `<script>` tag with the source from your 2nd snippet (the `[a,b]` snippet), you _don't_ see an error in Firefox or Edge?

Comment: @slebetman Thank you for noticing, I edited it, I was in fact refering to String.split()

Comment: @romellem Exaclty, when the source code of the second snippet is in a script tag, it does work, i do not see a reference error

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
....
const [timestamp_date, timestamp_time] = timestamp.split("T");
....
```

Comment: Yes i know that this fix the problem, but i wanted to know why I need to add const here but not in the second case

Comment: @AntoninL checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522523/1283345 might help