# Python-like unpacking in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unpack

I have the following string

```
output_string = "[10, 10, [1,2,3,4,5], [10,20,30,40,50]]"
```

Then I `JSON.parse` it

```
my_args = JSON.parse(output_string)
```

How do I unpack it in a Python-like way so that every element in `my_args` becomes an argument to a JavaScript function?

```
some_javascript_function(*my_args)
// should be equivalent to:
some_javascript_function(my_args[0],my_args[1],my_args[2],my_args[3])
// or:
some_javascript_function(10, 10, [1,2,3,4,5], [10,20,30,40,50])
```

Is there a core JavaScript idiom that does that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422458/unpacking-array-into-separate-variables-in-javascript

Comment: @arunkumar, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422458/unpacking-array-into-separate-variables-in-javascript/3422473#3422473) to that question looks interesting, which makes this a slightly different question. Can we do that for function arguments?

Comment: My apologies, you are right. It is not a duplicate. And there seems to be a way to do this in the answer below. I will remove the earlier comment, since its not relevant.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Once you 've collected the function arguments in an array, you can use the `apply()` method of the function object to invoke your predefined function with it:

```
   some_javascript_function.apply(this, my_args)
```

The first parameter (`this`) sets the context of the invoked function.

Comment: `.apply` works well, but `.call` doesn't quite hit it with an `Array` argument. Thanks, you've pointed me in the right direction. This article, [Function apply and function call in JavaScript](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) looks interesting.

Comment: Note this won't work for `console.log.apply(...)`. That should use `console.log.apply(console, arguments)`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159233/typeerror-illegal-invocation-on-console-log-apply).

Answer (score 41):

You can achieve that by doing this 
`some_javascript_function(...my_args)`

This is called `spread` operation (as `unpacking` is in python).
view docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 13):

## Unpack using "..."

The same way you accept unlimited args, you can unpack them.

```
let vals = [1, 2, 'a', 'b'];

console.log(vals);    // [1, 2, "a", "b"]
console.log(...vals); // 1 2 "a" "b"
```

### Example: Accept unlimited arguments into a function

It will become a list

```
const someFunc = (...args) => {
    console.log(args);    // [1, 2, "a", "b"]
    console.log(args[0]); // 1
    console.log(...args); // 1 2 "a" "b"
}

someFunc(1, 2, 'a', 'b');
```

### Example: Send list of arguments into a function

```
const someFunc = (num1, num2, letter1, letter2) => {
    console.log(num1);    // 1
    console.log(letter1); // "a"
}

let vals = [1, 2, 'a', 'b'];
someFunc(...vals);
```

Send arguments