# How to pass array of arrays as a series of variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of arrays:

```
[
  [1,2],
  [2,3],
  [4,3]
]
```

I want to pass them to a underscore-function as a series of variables.

```
_.intersection([1,2],[2,3],[4,3])
```

How can this be done?

Comment: This is called argument unpacking  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077651/python-like-unpacking-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `apply`

```
_.intersection.apply(_, myArr);
```

- The first parameter to the apply method is the `this` context to be set on the called method.
- The second parameter is an array whose elements will be passed as individual arguments to the called method.

[**MDN Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

> The apply() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).

Comment: _Please_ don't encourage users to ask questions without researching them, by answering them. Obvious duplicates like these should really be closed as such.