# Javascript: argument unpacking in function.prototype.bind()?

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, argument-unpacking

[The closest I've seen is this, but it doesn't really help me since I need to bind some parameters for later use with setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077651/python-like-unpacking-in-javascript).

More specifically:

```
[in] var d = function(l, m) {
       console.log(l);
       console.log(m);
     }
[in] d.apply(window, [1,2])
[out] 1
[out] 2
[out-return-value] undefined
[in] d.bind(window, [1,2])()
[out] [1, 2]
[out] undefined
[out-return-value] undefined
```

As can be seen, arrays are unpacked with `.apply()`, but not with `.bind()`. Is there any way to unpack the arguments with `.bind()`?

Comment: Seems I answered such a question before :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bind` is just another function. Call it with `.apply` if you want to call it with an array of arguments:

```
var bound = d.bind.apply(d, [window, 1, 2]);
// If the `this` value is known, but the arguments is an array, concat:
// var bound = d.bind.apply(d, [window].concat(args))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Function.prototype.bindArray(ctx, array) {
  if (array && array.length && array.pop && array.length > 0) {
    var v = array.pop();
    return this.bindArray(ctx, array).bind(ctx, v);
  }
  else return this;
};
```

It will iteratively bind every value in `array`.

Use it like:

```
var d = function(l, m) {
  console.log(l);
  console.log(m);
};
var c = d.bindArray(null, [1,2]);
c(); // 1 2
```

---

Also see below @felix's answer. That's even cool.

Comment: I really like this. Very elegant - nice!

Comment: Question: since I think I found a solution without iteration, would this work as well, or if not, why?:

`    Function.prototype.bindArray(thisArg, array) {`  
`        array.unshift(thisArg);`  
`        return this.bind.apply(this, array);`  
`    }`

Comment: This seems overly complex (for the task) and creates unnecessary intermediate function objects.

Comment: @13steinj yeah it works. This answer is actually cool.