# Add many values to Redis group SADD

Tags: python, node.js, redis

I have Python code:

```
redis.sadd(r_key, *set(r_list))
```

and it works excellent:
But I can't do the same on Node.js

```
redis.sadd(r_key, new Set(array), function(err) {})
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the library you are using 
You can use [IOREDIS](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) for node, where you can pass the array as an input parameter.

```
redis.sadd('r_key', 1, 3, 5, 7);
redis.sadd('r_key', [1, 3, 5, 7]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a problem about how to use flatten args in Js like python *.

You can read this doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis, It said, all the redis api is 1 to 1 mapping of redis server command.  so SADD is :

```
 SADD key member [member ...]
```

Your js code should be like above.  just a case:

```
 redis.sadd("key","member", "member", ...)
```

So you know why you code does not work.

To do this, you can refer this question : [Python-like unpacking in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077651/python-like-unpacking-in-javascript)

```
 redis.sadd.apply(this, args)
```

And the args is a array of key and your members string .