# If statement in for loop doesn't work, javascript

Tags: javascript

I got 7 variables (seconds), I am using them to show countdown. All of them counting down simultaneously at the same page. I want to set them to '59' after they reached to '0'. I am new to javascript so sorry if it is a silly question.

Here is my code :

```
s--; s2--; s3--; s4--; s5--; s6--; s7--; 

        var array_s = [s, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7]; 
        for (var i = 0; i < array_s.length; i++) {
            var result = array_s[i];
            if( result < 0) {
                result = 59;
            }
        }
```

Edit: tried this way, too:

```
var array_s = [s, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7]; 
for (var i = 0; i < array_s.length; i++) {
    if( array_s[i] < 0) {
        array_s[i] = 59;
    }
}
```

But they keep counting down after '0'. So, Where is my problem, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have edited the mistake in length

Comment: Check your spelling: `>lenght<`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `result` back to 59, but you're never setting that value back to the appropriate `sN` variable. Setting `array_s[i]` alone wouldn't work with your code as it is now, because that will just correct the values within the array, not the `sN` variables.

I'd recommend getting rid of the `sN` variables entirely and just using an array:

```
// initialize array once
var array_s = [...]; 

...

for (var i = 0; i < array_s.length; i++) {
    var result = array_s[i];
    result--;                // decrement each value
    if(result < 0) {         // check for values < 0
        result = 59;
    }
    array_s[i] = result;     // update values
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/8J2EG/)

Note: In this demonstration, I've significantly accelerated the timer so you can easily see the values decrementing down past 0 and resetting. Also, it's important to realize that `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are not particularly accurate, so if you really need to make your timers accurate down to the second, you'll probably need to use another method—e.g. using [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects.

Comment: @ctarimli The key thing is to get rid of the `sN` variables. See my updated answer for a demonstration of how this might work.

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo, `lenght` should be `length`.

Comment: :D sorry for this mistake and thank you, I changed it but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

primitive types such as 'result' is not a reference to the index in the array, its just the value.  You need to update the array.

```
if (result < 0)
  array_s[i] = 59
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't load it into the result var, and use `length`:

```
var array_s = [s, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7]; 
for (var i = 0; i < array_s.length; i++) {
    if( array_s[i] < 0) {
        array_s[i] = 59;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to update the variables from the array:
`[s, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7] = array_s;`
see Andy E's answer:
[Unpacking array into separate variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422458/unpacking-array-into-separate-variables-in-javascript)