# How to perform Array/Object destructuring manually & efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

[Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is super useful:

```
var [a, b, c] = [1, 2, 8];
```

It looks like it was [implemented into Javascript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29), but then [removed with bug 1083498](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1083498). Now according to [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility) it's not supported by any browser except Firefox! :(

I wish I could use it because I don't like having to create an extra unnecessary variable.

With destructuring:

```
var a, b, c;
var input = "1 2 8";
[a, b, c] = arr.split(" ");
```

Without destructuring:

```
var a, b, c;
var input = "1 2 8";
var inputArr = input.split(" ");
a = inputArr[0];
b = inputArr[1];
c = inputArr[2];
```

Is there a way to do this without the need to create the extra unneeded `inputArr` and draw from it multiple times?

Comment: The code in the second sample is far more readable.

Comment: It isn't possible. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422458/unpacking-array-into-separate-variables-in-javascript

Comment: `var a=1,b=2,c=8;`  is pretty short, fewer chars than destructuring actually...

Comment: @dandavis how would you do that given `input` which is a space-separated string with three unknown numbers?

Comment: i would just use the array, or make a LUT; no need for lexicals... (i rarely use vars)

Comment: @FelixSanz, your answer makes me unhappy, but is probably right. It's on the horizon with ECMAScript 6, but it looks like [support is still a long way off](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#destructuring).

Comment: @dandavis, I can't make sense of what you're saying.

Comment: @brentonstrine You can use Babel (http://babeljs.io/) Or any other ES6 transpiler