# Can someone help me to undestand "For of" ECMA6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

i wanna understand those results, why [key, value] work that way ? i dont understand how [key, value] return different in both code bellow since both are ECMA 6

```
let iterable = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]);
for (let [key, value] of iterable) {
  console.log(value);
}
// 1
// 2
// 3

var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(0, 'zero');
myMap.set(1, 'one');
for (var [key, value] of myMap) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}
// 0 = zero
// 1 = one
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpacking array into separate variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422458/unpacking-array-into-separate-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Unclear what difference you are asking about. The first `console.log` logs only values. The second logs both keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyse the code you've written:

- `let iterable = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]);` creates a new `Map` object, which is essentialy a set of `key-value` pairs. Nothing too fancy here.
- `let [key, value] of iterable` *deconstructs* the `iterable` object. This is a new ES6 feature that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables (more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [here](http://untangled.io/advanced-es6-destructuring-techniques/)).
- finally, `for (let [key, value] of iterable) {console.log(value)}` simply prints the `value` of each map entry (hence 1, 2 and 3 in your first example).