# exporting a variable and getting access to it

Tags: javascript, module

I'm using the code below to get access to variables in *variables.js* from *main.js*:

variables.js:

```
export default {
    bla: 123,
}
```

main.js:

```
var vars = require('./variables').default;
class MyClass extends blabla {
  constructor (){
    super();
  }

  myFunction (){
    console.log(vars.aa)
  }
}
```

in *main.js* to get access to variable I have to use `vars.bla`.

my question is How can I get access to it just with `bla`(yea to lazy)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244414/10060553
Maybe check this out? This might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? Could be a bad idea if you have the same variable name in both files. I think there's no way to do that, anyways. You'll have to make the variables manually. You could use destructuring. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422458/unpacking-array-into-separate-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variables.js:

```
module.exports = {
  bla:123
}
```

Other files:

```
var {bla} = require('./variables');
console.log(bla)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access it by using destructuring assignment like this:

```
let { bla } = require("./variables").default

console.log(bla)
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nnqw0pynk4