# How to create an individual array from an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I split an array into individual array:
[1,2,3,4,5] => [1][2][3][4][5]

The array of objects is gotten from a backend API

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Emmanuel',
    ...
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Emmanuel',
    ...
  }
]
```

Doing `arr.map(a => a.id)` gave me `[1,2,...]`, now how do I get individual array from the ids: `[1][2]`

Comment: where is the target of single arrays?

Comment: I think you need to give more clarity to the question because the answer from @NinaScholz would seem correct currently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a long array into smaller arrays, with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273668/how-to-split-a-long-array-into-smaller-arrays-with-javascript). In this case, the size of the "smaller arrays" is 1.

Comment: Or, if you want them as separate variables, [Unpacking array into separate variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3422458/215552)

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the return value in an array and take a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) into own targets.

```
let [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5] = arr.map(a => [a.id]);
```

Comment: This gave an array of array: `[[1][2]]`